# Adding a title caption to Supersized slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, supersized

I am using this fullscreen background slider from Supersized http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/. Currently my page displays the caption in the bottom (which is a functionality already built into the plugin). I don't know much jQuery, but essentially what I'm trying to get at is adding a different headline that slides in for each different background.

How do I go about this?

Comment: @Calvintwr is there a way maybe I can change the CSS for the #slide-list and have it say words instead of displaying the little circle slide links?

Comment: changing css on a slider to include a caption is one of the hardest things to do. I propose that you look for a slider that already has what you roughly need. You can modify it slightly, but if it doesn't even have close to what you need you are gonna tear hair over it. trust me i have been there and done that. there just isn't any easy way out.

Comment: Photoshop the caption onto the image.

Answer (score 0):

I used the drupal supersized initialisation script http://cgit.drupalcode.org/supersized/tree/js/supersized.js

It initialises a callback - supesrized_slide_callback(). There are callback hooks in supersized such as [jQuery Supersized AfterAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369470/jquery-supersized-afteranimation)

My code loads json and adapts to the css used by supersized. Add your own error checking.

```
jQuery.getJSON("sites/all/themes/mytheme/js/supersized_captions.json", function (data) {
   window.supsersizeddata = data;
});

window.supersized_slide_callback = function () {
  // jquery object method used.
  var details = this.supsersizeddata;

  var active_slide = jQuery('.activeslide');

  // hasOwnProperty
  if (active_slide.hasClass('slide-0')) {
   jQuery('.field-name-body').html(details['slide-0']);
  }
};
```

The JSON:

```
{
  "slide-0": ["<h2>Centaurus A</h2>"]
}
```

Extended as needed for each slide